# Scoping issues when using Jasmine to test Polymer components

Tags: mocking, jasmine, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I am trying to test a simple bit of javascript associated with a polymer element. The javascript has been abstracted out of the home of the element, so I am using 'polymerElement' to refer to it. The code simply adds a class:

```
OpenPanel: () => {
    polymerElement.$$('.panel').classList.add('panel-visible');
}
```

In jasmine, I have created a panel element, but am stuck as to how to retrieve that element when calling the OpenPanel method, as jasmine does not know what polymerElement or $$ are.

I am getting the error: 'polymerElement.$$ is not a function'

Comment: It sounds like `polymerElement` is not actually a Polymer instance. One way to confirm that is with: `Polymer.isInstance(polymerElement)`. Can you provide more code context around `polymerElement`'s assignment and `OpenPanel`?

Comment: To get round this issue, I had to create a mock polymer object with a '$$' method which simply returned an object which in turn returned a classList object with 'add' and 'remove' methods.

Whether there is an easier way of doing this, I'm not sure.